# Sudo no longer available and users can't install or modify most files

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sudo

I recently started messing with some files on a virtual hosted machine and I was logged in a normal/non-root user. At first everything was fine, I was able to install anything I needed using:

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

But I somehow messed up a file where now when I do that I get the following error:

```
sudo: can't open /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

I'm not sure how to diagnose this, I've googled for solutions but everything's about what sudo is and nothing related to what to do about re-enabling users to use it.

Let me know if you'd like any other details in comments :)

**Edit:**

```
ls -l /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- 1 root root 577 Apr 20 03:42 /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: Login as root and tell us what this looks like: `ls -l /etc/sudoers`

Comment: just added it to the edit

Comment: Hmm. That's still not giving up any clues. How about `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo` (or wherever `which sudo` tells you the sudo executable is at)

Comment: This could happen if there is a problem with group permissions.  Did you recently make any changes to `/etc/group`?  Did you install `sudo` using your own `./configure` arguments?  Is group 0 `root` or `wheel`?  If it's wheel, you'll need to run `chgrp wheel /etc/sudoers` as root.

Comment: I didn't mess with sudo to change anything related to it. I might've deleted something but not sure what I'm missing. how do I find out what group 0 is?

Comment: Simplest way: `getent group 0`.  Other way: `head -1 /etc/group`.

Comment: What virtualization technology? Is SELinux or AppArmor active?

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of things that could be failing, but given your output of `ls -l /etc/sudoers`, most of them are ruled out.

First a couple of quick checks:

1. what does `type sudo` print?
2. what does `getent group 0` print?

Then, to properly see what's going on, can you log in as root using `su -`, then run this?

```
# apt-get install ltrace
# ltrace -u <username> sudo true 2>&1  | egrep '(sudo|stat|set.*[ug].*id)'
```

and/or

```
# apt-get install strace
# strace -u <yourusername> sudo true 2>&1 | egrep '(sudo|set.*[ug].*id)'
```

And add the output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, you can copy the `/etc/sudoers` file to a backup location, then `apt-get --reinstall install sudo`